# database backup script generating file of different sizes?

Tags: backup, scp

I am using the following script to create a database backup and sending it to a storage location using scp.

What I noticed is that the resulting file very frequently delivers a seemingly correct file. For the most of the time, the file size is around the 3GiB mark, but sometimes the resulting file is some 900B, sometimes 2.2MiB.

The script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

# database credentials

DATABASEHOST=<host>
DATABASEUSER=<user>
DATABASEPASSWORD=<password>
DATABASESCHEMA=<schema>
DATABASEENV=<env>

# Local directory of mysqldump file
LOCALDIR=<localdir>

# Temporary directory for compressed file
TEMPDIR=<tempdir>

# Remote Directory for backups.
REMOTEDIR=<remote-dir>

# USERname to login as
BACKUPUSER=<backupuser>

# Backup host to login to
BACKUPHOST=<backuphost>

# mysqldump file
MYSQLDUMPFILE="$(date +%Y%m%d)"_bkp_"$DATABASESCHEMA".sql

# compressed file
COMPRESSEDFILE="$(date +%Y%m%d)"_"$DATABASEENV"_"$DATABASESCHEMA".tar.gz

#--- end config


echo $(date +%H:%M)
echo "Creating the MySQL dump" 
mysqldump --host="$DATABASEHOST" --user="$DATABASEUSER" --password="$DATABASEPASSWORD" --single-transaction "$DATABASESCHEMA" > "$LOCALDIR"/"$MYSQLDUMPFILE"

#echo "Generating md5sum"
md5sum "$LOCALDIR"/* > "$LOCALDIR"/checklist.chk

#echo "Compressing the dump and checklist"
tar -cvzf "$TEMPDIR"/$(date +%Y%m%d)"_"$DATABASEENV"_"$DATABASESCHEMA".tar.gz" "$LOCALDIR"/*

#echo "Sending the compressed file to storage location"
scp "$TEMPDIR"/"$COMPRESSEDFILE" "$BACKUPHOST":"$REMOTEDIR"

echo "Removing generated files"
rm "$LOCALDIR"/checklist.chk > /dev/null 2>&1

rm "$LOCALDIR"/"$MYSQLDUMPFILE" > /dev/null 2>&1

rm "$TEMPDIR"/"$COMPRESSEDFILE" > /dev/null 2>&1

echo $(date +%H:%M)
```

Since most of the times the resulting file is ok, I'm thinking the problem may rely on the scp part.

How can I ensure the storage location generated file is the same as the original and, if they're different, try to scp again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use rsync please. Rsync checks md5 hash of file.

[rsync examples](http://www.tecmint.com/rsync-local-remote-file-synchronization-commands/)

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.